# How to read my csv file in Fortran?

Tags: csv, fortran

How to read following data in Fortran. I'm not able to read data in this file. I'm getting following error

```
severe (64): input conversion error, unit 18

Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
a.out              00000000004734AA  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

This is my code:

```
        program dataread
        implicit none
        character*15 ::head_1,head_2,head_3,head_4,head_5,head_6
        character*15:: B,C, head_7,head_8,head_9,head_10
        real,dimension(1:71385,1:10)::A
        integer::i,j

        open(unit=18, file='Tws15thHourlyData.csv' , status='old',
     &  access ='sequential',form='formatted')!,recl=71781*10)

        read(18,*) head_1,head_2,head_3,head_4,head_5,head_6,
     &          head_7,head_8, head_9,head_10


       do i=2,71385
       read(18,300)(A(i,j),j=1,10)
300    format(I5,A17,2F9.6,A8,5F4.1)
       end do

        print*, head_1,head_2,head_3,head_4,head_5,head_6,
     &          head_7,head_8,   head_9,head_10
       do i=2,71385
       read(18,300)(A(i,j),j=1,10)
300    format(I5,A17,2F9.6,A8,5F4.1)
       end do

        print*, head_1,head_2,head_3,head_4,head_5,head_6,
     &          head_7,head_8,   head_9,head_10


        do i=2,71385
              print*, (A(i,j),j=1,10)
        end do
        close(18)
        open(unit=28,file='14data.txt')
        write(28, 100),((A(i,j),j=1,10),i=2,71385)
100     format(10(71385(I4,A15,2F9.6,A8,5F4.1,2x),/))
        end program
```

This data I'm trying to read

```
TWSCODE,DISTRICT,LATITUDE_DD,LONGITUDE_DD,RECORDED_DATE,HOUR,TEMPERATURE,HUMIDITY,WIND_SPEED,WIND_DIRECTION

109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,0,26.2,79.4,0,168
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,0,26.2,80,0,25

109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,0,26.1,80.4,0,25
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,0,25.9,81,0,25

109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,1,25.8,81.7,0,25
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,1,25.9,82,0,287
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,1,25.9,82.5,0,299
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,1,25.8,82.8,0,286
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,2,25.6,83.5,0,254
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,2,25.6,83.9,0,292
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,2,25.6,84,0,299
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,2,25.6,84.2,0,309
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,3,25.5,84.4,0,327
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,3,25.4,84.8,0,315
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,3,25.3,84.8,0,305
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,3,25.2,84.8,0,306
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,4,25.2,84.9,0,305
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,4,25.2,85.1,0,306
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,4,25.1,85.3,0,305
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,4,25.1,85.4,0,305
109,KALABURAGI,17.463587,77.42,14-08-17,5,25.1,85.7,0,308
```

Comment: I can't see any code. Anyway, what kind of problems did you encounter when you tried your code? Please show the code and describe what is wrong. Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: So what happens when you use your code? There is no question in your post. What do you want to know? Do you have any problem with the code you show? We can't read your mind. You must ask a question.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? How do you compile your code? Please use all the debugging features your compiler offers. (`gfortran -g -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all`, `ifort -g -traceback -warn -check`).

Comment: To do a formatted read you need to "read" the commas, declare a length 1 character string and include that repeatedly on the read line and add appropriate `a`'s to the format.  Alternately list read the whole line as strings and internal read what you need from the strings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I dislike @agentp's answer and flat out disagree with the comment that one should read the line as a string and mess about parsing it.

So I wrote this ...

As I pointed out in a comment above one of the errors (possibly the only one) in OP's code is using this statement, and format

```
       read(18,300)(A(i,j),j=1,10)
300    format(I5,A17,2F9.6,A8,5F4.1)
```

for trying to read a mixture of numbers and strings into an array of `reals`.  That's never going to work out well.  Take a step back and give the matters some thought.  The input file contains some nicely-structured data, so why not define a nice structure for storing it ?  First a type definition something like:

```
  TYPE :: met_record
     INTEGER :: TWSCODE
     CHARACTER(len=32) :: DISTRICT
     REAL :: LATITUDE_DD
     REAL :: LONGITUDE_DD
     CHARACTER(len=8) :: RECORDED_DATE
     INTEGER :: HOUR
     REAL :: TEMPERATURE
     REAL :: HUMIDITY
     REAL :: WIND_SPEED
     REAL :: WIND_DIRECTION
  END TYPE met_record
```

then an array of those

```
TYPE(met_record), DIMENSION(71385) :: weather_reports
```

Now reading the data is very easy indeed ...

```
do i = 1, 71385
    read(18,*) weather_reports(i)
end do
```

Look ! Not an explicit format in sight.  Declare variables properly and let Fortran parse the input line.

Note:

- I write relatively modern Fortran and have no truck with fixed-form source files.
- I've not made any arrangements for reading the file header, there is already code for that.
- Writing a `met_record` can be as simple as `write(28,*)  weather_reports(i)`

Comment: Hi @High Performance Mark I've the same problem of Ajay with the difference that my first column contains string with numbers and words separated by a white space; while in the second column I have words between round brackets. Debugging of my code is ok but I have all zeros in my defined data type. Can you help me? Can you post the complete program by using the example of the question of this topic?

Answer (score 1):

this is one approach:

```
 integer,parameter :: n=71385
 character*15 :: strings(10,n)
 real :: a(7,n)
 integer :: tw(n)
```

..

```
 do i=1,n
   read(18,*)strings(:,i)
   read(strings(1,i),*)tw(i)
   read(strings(3:4,i),*)a(1:2,i)
   read(strings(6:10,i),*)a(3:7,i)
 end do
```

note as an aside that i transposed the arrays, so that the assignment is to contiguous memory positions.